# data loss from django template during page reload

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, aptana

I am passing a variable to the django template from view file

view.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    t_t = request.POST.get('t_t')
    t_o = T(user_id=1, t=t, d=d)
    t_o.save()
    return render_to_response("t/t.html",{'t' :t_o},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

html file

```
#...#
{{t.d}}
#...#
```

The problem is that i am getting the value in the html template for the first time but when i try to reload the page , page content is lost ie. value that i passed from view is lost.

Am i doing it wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will only get the value if the request method is `POST`. Are you sure you are making `POST` request second time also??

Comment: Can you post the full view method? Take into account that when you refresh, the request might be of type `GET` instead of `POST`

Comment: @PauloBu can u explain???

Comment: I was just asking you to add to the question the full view method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reload the page you are most likely not performing a `POST` request

your data is only being retrieved from `POST` request

`if request.method == 'POST':`

You could change this to allow for `GET` querystring data as well as `POST`, if it fits your requirements:

`request.REQUEST.get('t_t')`

Comment: did not understand..can u explain??